# Is it possible to use CTE for the data exist in one table, not 2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

Imagine a factory for producing credit/debit cards, where the card will go through different stages of production. For example, a card will go through a `molding` stage, then will pass through a `printing` stage. Sometimes if there's problem the card will be sent back to the previous stages.

I want to write a query to find all cards that went through `printing` but is sent back `molding` (since `molding` is prior to `printing`).

What would be the way to "link" the cards data that exist both stages (they are in the same table):

```
select distinct barcode
from [Audit]..Stages (nolock)
where clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
    and stagename = 'printing'
    and Description <> 'Success'

select distinct barcode
from [Audit]..Stages (nolock)
where clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
    and stagename = 'Molding'
   and Description = 'Success'
```

I'm confused on the right way to "filter" since all the data exist in 1 table, not 2.

```
;
with failure as (
    select distinct barcode
    from [Audit]..Stages (nolock)
    where clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
        and stagename = 'printing'
        and Description <> 'Success'
)

success as (select distinct jt.jtpsid, jt.jtbarcode
from failure
with failure as (
    select distinct barcode
    from [Audit]..Stages (nolock)
    where clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
    and stagename = 'Molding'
    and Description = 'Success')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please also provide the SQL dialect or vendor you're using, because the solutions or syntax depend on it eg: mssql, postgres, mysql, all have slightly different approaches.

Comment: In this case, the `DB..table` syntax and `nolock` hints strongly indicate SQL Server.

Comment: Why are you using `nolock` are you aware of the serious data integrity issues it has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select all cards that are currently in the `molding` stage, and also have a `printing` stage where the date for the stage did not succeed. To do this you can `JOIN` the table to itself:

```
SELECT distinct barcode
FROM [Audit]..Stages s0
INNER JOIN [Audit]..Stages s1 ON s1.barcode = s0.barcode 
    AND s1.stagename = 'printing'
    AND s1.Description <> 'Success'
WHERE s0.stagename = 'molding'
    AND s0.Description = = 'success'
```

This would be even better if you can know the date of the `s1` record is **older** than for the `s0` record, since I expect there's probably also some kind of `in-process` stage that is also not a success.

Also, get rid of those `(nolock)` hints. They probably are not accomplishing what you've been led to believe... at least, not in a safe way. `(nolock)` can make a database faster by ignoring certain locks. This comes at the risk of reading stale data. The thing is, *the performance is only improved in those situations when the risk of reading stale data is much higher.* If there's no stale data, then there wouldn't be a lock to ignore.

Comment: "reading stale data" if it's uncommitted inserts I wouldn't call it stale, just not valid. And there is also a risk of douoble-reading or missing rows altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set operators

```sql
select
  s.barcode
from Stages s
where s.clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
  and s.stagename = 'printing'
  and s.Description <> 'Success'

intersect

select
  s.barcode
from Stages s
where s.clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
  and s.stagename = 'Molding'
  and s.Description = 'Success';
```

You can also use conditional aggregation

```sql
select
  s.barcode
from Stages s
where s.clientID = 'AmericanExpress'
  and s.stagename = 'printing'
group by
  s.barcode
having count(case when s.stagename = 'Molding'  and s.Description =  'Success' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when s.stagename = 'printing' and s.Description <> 'Success' then 1 end) > 0;
```